# FME Desktop Distorts shapefile to TDRBM(.bas) translation

Tags: shapefile, convert, fme-form

I am trying to convert esri shapefile into [Tobin TDRBM II Data Distribution Format](http://www.safe.com/fme/format-search/tobin-tdrbm-ii-data-distribution-format/index.php) (.bas) but this distorts my data and create files with extension `.bas.csv` instead of `.bas`.I removed `.csv` and tried to import in global mapper.My shapefile is in WGS84. I tried both specifying and not specifying the coordinate system in the FME but all went in vain.

Before translation-
[image: demo]

After translation-
[image: demo1]

Even i lost my attributes in the shapefile after translation!

---

**My FME details:**

```
Edition: FME Desktop Professional Edition (floating)
Version: FME(R) 2016.1.0.0 (20160419 - Build 16492 - WIN64)
Locale: en_US
Codepage: 1252 (ANSI - Latin I)
```

Comment: Can you show us a screenshot of your FME workspace?  It looks like the X and Y are being swapped or something...